# como evitar division en cero con php jalando formula de una tabla

Tags: javascript, php

tengo una consulta
resulta que necesito tomar de un campo la formula $TS04 trae la formula
$TT04 = eval("return ".$TS04.";");

pero al dividir en cero me da este error
Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\Objetivos\Calc41Pers.php(471) : eval()'d code on line 1

y como controlo que no de error siemple mente que no haga la operacion ya que la operacion es de una tabla

aqui dejo mi codigo

leo de una tabla y saco valores de campo numerico

```
if ($CUADP_VALOR1='N'  && $tipform == '$SS08' ){
                                                $SS08=$row3["imp2"];    }
                                            if ($CUADP_VALOR1='N'  &&  $tipform == '$SS09') {
                                               $SS09=$row3["imp2"];}
                                            if ($CUADP_VALOR1='N'  &&  $tipform == '$SS10' )    {
                                               $SS10=$row3["imp2"]; }
                                            if ($CUADP_VALOR1='N'  &&  $tipform == '$SS11' )    {
                                               $SS11=$row3["imp2"]; }
```

---

con base en los valores en

```
$TS01=$formu;(valor de la formula es $TT02=(($SS11+($SS12*0.8))/$SS09)*100)

                                            if ($CUADP_VALOR1 ='C' && $tipform == '$TT01'){
                                                $e1='$TT01';
                                                $var=$fol3;
                                                $TS01=$formu;
                                                $TT01 = eval("return ".$TS01.";");
```

y lo que necesito es que no marque error aunque este en cero

Comment: El problema es que $SS09 no puede ser cero por una restricción propia de las reglas de la aritmética en la que el denominador en una división, cuando vale cero, arroja un resultado inválido en el campo de los números reales (infinito).
Una solución que te puede ser útil es que cuando tu programa recibe el valor de $SS09, antes de usarla, con una sentencia ```if``` (o con el operador ternario) lo conviertas a un valor pequeño tan cercano a 0 como convenga a la lógica del sistema, de modo que el resultado sea útil al proceso (por ejemplo 0.1 o 0.000001)

Answer (score 1):

Prueba lo siguiente:

Sustituye esto:

```php
$TT01 = eval("return ".$TS01.";");
```

por esto

```php
$TT01 = ($SS09 !== 0 )? eval("return ".$TS01.";") : 'División por 0';
```

Y dinos si con eso ya te vale.

Comment: la cuestion es que yo no se que valor es la variable $SS09 ya que cambia por eso es mi problema

Comment: No, tu problema es solo cuando $SS09 vale 0, por eso he puesto eso de `($SS09 !==0) ?`... ¿has probado de sustituir la linea que te he dicho?  Es probable que luego te de otro error mas adelante, si usas la variable $TT01 despues como numero para más cálculos, porque si $SS09 equivale a 0 entonces la relleno con un texto que pone "División por cero" porque no se para que la usas despues

Answer (score 1):

Pero, ¿por qué no usas el `try ... catch` de toda la vida?

PHP lanza un [`DivisionByZeroError`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.divisionbyzeroerror.php) cuando intentas dividir por cero.

Por tanto, puedes controlar dentro de un bloque `try ... catch` del siguiente modo:

```
try 
{
    // Aquí que código que intenta la división
} 
catch (DivisionByZeroError $e) 
{
    // Imprimir $e o hacer otra cosa

}
```